# How to get FireFox recognize certificate on my computer to authenticate myself

Tags: firefox

When I use Chrome or Edge and load a site, it prompts me to select a certificate to authenticate myself. But when I load the same site with fireFox, it does not prompt me the same.

I am using Windows 10, with the latest edition of FF and Chrome.

How can I enable that to work in Firefox?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome and Edge use certificates in the global Windows (CryptoAPI) certificate store.

Firefox does not support that; you must export the certificate to a PKCS#12 (PFX) file, then import it into Firefox's own (NSS) certificate store through the settings/preferences screen.

- https://www.jscape.com/blog/firefox-client-certificate
- https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1211486-install-client-digital-certificate---firefox-for-windows

If the certificates are on a smartcard, you must load a PKCS#11 module for your smartcard (through "Security Devices" in the same window). Most smartcard manufacturers provide both CAPI and PKCS#11 drivers.

(If the certificates are stored by Windows but non-exportable, you'll need a PKCS#11 "bridge" module that can access the Windows store. Unfortunately, all the ones I've found are either commercial and expensive, or free and broken.)

Comment: How can i find the cert and 'export the certificate to a PKCS#12 (PFX) file'?